# PHPExcel print array result as HTML table in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using PHPExcel and CodeIgniter to make an application. I have my Model for Excel treatment:

```
class modelExcel extends CI_Model
{
  protected $excel;

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('Excel');
  }

  function readReport() { //Função para retorno dos dados do arquivo Excel
    $this->excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(APPPATH."/exceldata/wf.xlsx");

    //Seleciona a planilha ativa
    $objWorksheet = $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('D7:J7');

    return $objWorksheet;
  }
}
```

My Main Page Controller where I get all the data and send to a view:

```
public function index() {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged')) {
            $this->load->model('ModelExcel');
            $data['excel'] = $this->ModelExcel->readReport();
            $sessionData = $this->session->userdata('logged');
            $data['username'] = $sessionData['userName'];
            $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('home');
            $this->load->view('template/footer');   
        }
```

And finally my View (have more code, but here's exactly where I want to print the table):

```
<div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-6">
        <?=$excel?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doing exactly as this are, I got an error of array to string conversion. Have some another way to print excel specific columns and rows?

Comment: I can only assume that `$excel` is in fact an array. Just loop over it in your view and echo whatever needs echo-ing.

Comment: As @Andrew says: you are using short tags which means `<?php echo $excel;?>`. Echo function can't show an array output. You should use `<?php print_r($excel);?>`. [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) | [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your tip! I solved my problem with "foreach", will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with "foreach". Here's the final code:

```
foreach ($excelData as $dataArray) {
            foreach ($dataArray as $dataValue) {
                echo $dataValue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$objWorksheet` will be a 2-dimensional array, rows and columns, with 1 row and 7 columns, so you'll need to iterate over that row to get the array of columns, and then iterate over those columns to get the individual cell values for display in your view